# Angular stanndalone component issue: imports' must be an array of components, directives, pipes, or NgModules

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-standalone-components

I update my application to angular v15 and try to refactor a component to be Standalone.

When import dependencies in this component I got this error:

> 'imports' must be an array of components, directives, pipes, or NgModules.
> Value is of type '[CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatDialogModule, MatButtonModule, (not statically analyzable), MatIconModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule]'.

All dependencies are relative to angualr material and angualr.

```
@Component({
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
    ],
    selector: 'app-address-add-form',
    templateUrl: 'address-add-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['address-add-form.component.scss']
})
```

for fix this issue I create a shared module then import shared module to this standalone component.

```
@Component({
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        SharedModule
    ],
    selector: 'app-address-add-form',
    templateUrl: 'address-add-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['address-add-form.component.scss']
})
})
```

why for this component I can't directly imports dependencies?

Comment: Your error is specifically picking out MatCardModule? Double check the imports etc.

Comment: Thanks for helping. MatCardModule didn't import but the error message doesn't clear at all.

Comment: Do you have a new error message?

Comment: No, just import issue was the problem

Comment: @AlixDehghani why don't you submit your own answer so that others can also benefit?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is your issue :[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0jJh.png)

This can be resolved by adding the following inputs to the component:

```js
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
```

May be this can resolve, Please try this.